# Email Notification Sugar CRM

Tags: sugarcrm

When any user delete a record then email need to be send to particular user and Admin user as well. I am using sugar CRM Pro and i have also tried workflows but there is no action for delete of a module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [after_delete](http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/03_Module_Framework/Logic_Hooks/02_Module_Hooks/after_delete) logic hook and [SugarPHPMailer](http://developers.sugarcrm.com/wordpress/2011/08/15/howto-send-and-archive-an-email-in-sugar-via-php/) to send message on deleting records.